# Jquery show render page in gridview yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I am trying to create feedback page by put gridview on the page to show the feedbacklist, and I have plan to put the list replay under the current comment.

[image]
This is the following code I made:

```
  'columns' => [
        [   'attribute' => 'iduser.photo',
            'format' => 'html',
            'value'=>  function($data) { return Html::img($data->imageurl) . " <p class='feedback-username'>" . $data->username . "</p>"; },
            'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 10px; max-height: 10px'],
        ],

        [   'attribute' => 'KOMENTAR',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($model) { return $model->KOMENTAR  ."<br><p class='feedback-date'>". $model->TANGGAL ."</p><hr><div id='replay'><ul></ul></div>";},
        ],

        [   'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'width: 5px;'],
            'template' => '{update} {delete}',
            'visible' => !Yii::$app->user->isGuest,
        ],
```

I want to use jQuery for slip list replay in id = replay > ul

This the controller I made:

```
public function actionReplay()
{
    $searchModel = new FeedbackSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->searchReplay();;

    return $this->render('replay', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
    ]);
}
```

And this is the model:

```
public function searchReplay()
{
    $dataProvider = Feedback::find()->where("REPLAYED = '1'")->all();
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

The view to show the list:

```
<?php
foreach ($dataProvider as $model) 
{
    echo $model->KOMENTAR;
}
```

How can i put the list data in grid view?
I think of jquery but i still have no idea.